# Random Name Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have a working function in this random name generator, but it always ends up returning 'undefined' at some point. I've tried subtracting 1 from the array to prevent it from going too far, but that's not changing anything. How might I test this and debug it?

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xugeg/1/edit)

Comment: Rounding up will get you the undefined in some cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `Math.round()` when you should be using `Math.floor()`.

By rounding, you'll sometimes end up with the random index being the length of the array, and so that'll be an undefined element.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Looks like I need to read up more on the math methods.

Answer (score 1):

Change this row:

> var random = arry[Math.round(Math.random() * arry.length)];

To
this:

> var random = arry[Math.round(Math.random() * (arry.length - 1))];

Comment: Already tried that @petar, looks like I should be using Math.floor instead.

Comment: I was mistaken, I did this. var random = arry[Math.round(Math.random() * arry.length) - 1];

Comment: Just was thinking why you still get "undefined" :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to look more carefully from now on :)